# Infinite Loop When Piping Get-ChildItem to Import-CSV

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me understand why this produces an infinite loop? I've been searching for 2 days on how to fix this. I am trying to import a folder of CSV files and its driving me crazy.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Path C:\users\misnomer\documents\csvFiles).FullName | Import-CSV
```

Comment: What makes you believe this is an infinite loop? How many CSV there are in this directory? What's the total size of the CSVs?

Comment: 63 CSV files and each one is 1kb with roughly 13-20 rows and 2 columns in each CSV. Not much at all.

Comment: Do all CSVs have the same headers? And are there any files with characters like `[` or `]` in their name?

Comment: Each one is a different user with a different name. The format is Admin-FirstName Lastname.csv

Comment: What happens if you try this: `Import-CSV -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Path C:\users\misnomer\documents\csvFiles).FullName`

Comment: That worked! Mucho gracias!

Comment: No problem. You likely have characters that shouldn't be used in paths or file names hence the use of `-LiteralPath`